# Keep Only Unique Values In Array

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I have an obj like this:

```
$str([1,2,3,1,2,4,5])
```

I want to remove similar values from the array I want an output like:

```
$str([3,4,5])
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try googling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to count the unique terms in the array. Once you have that array just iterate over it and see if the term is present only once.

```
$str = array(1,2,3,1,2,4,5);
$array = array_count_values($str);
foreach($array as $value => $count) {
    if($count == 1) {
        $unique[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/4rTZE